# Typescript compiler gives 'Unresolved variable or type' when I use a 'Token' in Angular2 provider() aliasing

Tags: typescript, angular

Typscript can't seem to handle a 'Token' as used in a Angular2 `provide()` aliasing function.  I'm wondering if there is a setting in the typescript compiler to fix that, or if I am stuck using a string type alias instead.

An example, as it would appear in `main.ts` bootstrapping function is as follows:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(**alias_token**, Child1aComponent)]);
```

Typescript (in webstorm, btw) reports an 'Unresolved variable or type alias_token' error.

There is an alternate 'provide' function that takes a string as param 1, but I'd prefer to use the Token version if possible.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**alias_token**` needs to be a valid type (that actually exists and is imported) or alternatively a string or an [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)

Some examples

```
class AliasToken {}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(AliasToken, {useClass  Child1aComponent})]);
...
constructor(private alias:AliasToken);
```

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide('alias_token', {useClass: Child1aComponent})]);
...
constructor(@Inject('alias_token') private alias:AliasToken);
```

```
var alias_token = new OpaqueToken("alias");
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(alias_token, {useClass: Child1aComponent})]);
...
constructor(@Inject(alias_token) private alias:AliasToken);
```

Comment: Opaque Token = perfect.  Thanks for the help.